# How many cards can I hold? (How do conflicting effects work?)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How many cards can I hold? Normally, I'd have 7, but card text trumps rules.

On my field, I have [Null Profusion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNull%20Profusion%5d) and [Kruphix, God of Horizons](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKruphix%2c%20God%20of%20Horizons%5d):

[image: Null Profusion]
[image: Kruphix, God of Horizons]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Murgatroid. The cards are Null Profusion and Kruphix, God of Horizons

Comment: This is not exactly what the question ask but just in case you where wondering the maximum hand size only forces you to discard at the end of your turn. Don't think you have to discard your cards the moment you have three cards in hand with that black enchantment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends, whichever one entered the battlefield last is the one that takes effect.

When a permanent enters the battlefield it receives a timestamp. Then when determining the result of continuous effects (the kind generated by both Kruphix and Null Profusion) you apply them in timestamp order.

So if the Profusion entered last you will have a max hand size of 2, and if Kruphix entered last you won't have a maximum hand size. If they were to enter the battlefield at the same time then the Active Player (the player whose turn it currently is) decides what the order of the timestamps is.

> **613.6.** Within a layer or sublayer, determining which order effects are applied in is usually done using a timestamp system. An effect with an earlier timestamp is applied before an effect with a later timestamp.
>
> **613.6c** An object receives a timestamp at the time it enters a zone.
>
> **613.6j** If two or more objects would receive a timestamp simultaneously, such as by entering a zone simultaneously or becoming attached simultaneously, the active player determines their relative timestamp order at that time.
>
> **613.10.** Some continuous effects affect game rules rather than objects. For example, effects may modify a player’s maximum hand size, or say that a creature must attack this turn if able. These effects are applied after all other continuous effects have been applied. Continuous effects that affect the costs of spells or abilities are applied according to the order specified in rule 601.2f. All other such effects are applied in timestamp order. See also the rules for timestamp order and dependency (rules 613.6 and 613.7).

Comment: @diego Awesome. Thanks! Another question: what if two things entered at the same time? E.g. If Kruphix and Null Profusion were now both 3CMC creatures, and I played Collected Company (which bring in two 3-or-lower-CMC creatures)

Comment: You may also want to quote 613.10, to show that timestamps apply to these effects even though they aren't part of the normal layer system.

Comment: @Tony "**613.6j** If two or more objects would receive a timestamp simultaneously, such as by entering a zone simultaneously or becoming attached simultaneously, **the active player determines their relative timestamp order at that time.**"

Comment: I want to note that "active player" means "the player who is taking the turn", **not** "the player who controls the objects", which may lead to some unwanted outcomes if you cast Collected Company on your opponent's turn.

Comment: @diego Also, one more note: 613.6a is also relevant here. I'm not sure if referencing it is necessary, though.

Comment: It might be useful to point out potential interactions with effects that increase or decrease maximum hand size (e.g. Gnat Miser) because it works differently for Null Profusion vs. Kruphix, God of Horizons.

Comment: It doesn't really work differently. You still just apply all of the effects in order, and then use the number you end up with.

Comment: It might not be clear that the order doesn't matter if the only effects are "you have no maximum hand size" and various increased/decreased hand size effects.

Comment: So by Active Player means "player whose turn it is" not "player who currently has priority"? Thus if I put both of these cards in on my opponents turn, he gets to pick which one 'counts'?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what order they entered the battlefield. Rule 613.10 says that we apply game rule-changing effects in timestamp order. Rule 613.6 explains how timestamps work. Whichever entered the battlefield later[1] has the later timestamp, which applies second and overrides the earlier effect.

> **613.10**. Some continuous effects affect game rules rather than objects. For example, effects may modify a player’s maximum hand size, or say that a creature must attack this turn if able. These effects are applied after all other continuous effects have been applied. Continuous effects that affect the costs of spells or abilities are applied according to the order specified in rule 601.2f. All other such effects are applied in timestamp order. See also the rules for timestamp order and dependency (rules 613.6 and 613.7).
>
> **613.6**. Within a layer or sublayer, determining which order effects are applied in is usually done using a timestamp system. An effect with an earlier timestamp is applied before an effect with a later timestamp.

---

[1] Technically, there are ways to "refresh" the timestamp of a permanent, so the order they entered the battlefield is not always the same as their timestamp order, but none of those ways applies in the situation as described.